# How do I place a div on top of another div while maintaining alignment without using position:absolute?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble placing a rectangle over another rectangle in a resume template I am trying to create. I want to be able to do it without using absolute positioning but nothing is working after a few hours of research. I tried using relative positioning and using a z-index but no luck. There is also a problem where the left most rectangle has some space between the rectangle and the edge of the page. I removed the left margins on my A4 page but still there's a gap between the container div and the A4 page no matter what I do. Any help would be appreciated.

Code in Question:

```
<page size="A4">
<div class="container">
    <div class="over-rect"></div>
    <div class="blue-rect">
        <span class="name">Name</span>
        <div class="icon">
            <img class="education" src="img/education.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</page>
```

Having some pasting issues so the rest of the code can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/p2g95e04/2/

I am trying to create something similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKaJp.jpg
However you can see in the picture, the blue rectangle has a gap between itself and the edge of the page that I am also trying to remove. If someone can point me in the right direction on how to approach these two problems, I would appreciate it a lot.

Edit: Clarity on gap issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajc0l.jpg

If I remove the outside container div, it fixes the problem but messes other things up so I was wondering how I could get it to work inside the container div.

Edit2: Changing the box shadow parameters removes the gap but I can't find a way to keep the shadow without removing the A4 paper.

Comment: In the image you shared, it looks like you want to give red background to Name?

Comment: @SwaroopDeval that is correct but I want to do it using a separate rectangle so that I can also place them elsewhere in the blue rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative margin, there's an example

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxterbo4/10/

```
 <div class="blue-rect">
   <div class="over-rect"></div>
     <span class="name">Name</span>
     <div class="icon">
       <img class="education" src="img/education.png">
     </div>
 </div>


.over-rect {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

.container>div.blue-rect>span.name {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it recommended to not use negative margins? Why does that even work in the first place? Also the issue where the blue rectangle is still separated by a gap from the left side of the page is still there. Would negative margins fix that too?
To clarify the gap issue: https://imgur.com/a/UHqORE5

Comment: you could really just do away with the second container and use a background color/image, negative margin works here because the div.over-rect is before the name span.name and by default has a lower z-index elements overlap in the order that they are delcared unless overriden by the z-index property

Comment: your padding issue is because the css framework gives the container a padding you just need to override it https://jsfiddle.net/rbw0g13p/ as for the negative margin I can't think of any reason against it but there's probably a better solution as mentioned in the above comment, however your question was how to lay a div on top of another div without position absolute and negative margin is the answer to that question.